# viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear not called while viewDidLoad called when something is in the UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

I'm having a strange problem when populating a `UIViewController`.

So, from the root, I'm making a Drawer in my app [with `MMDrawerController`](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) like:

```
self.drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                         initWithCenterViewController:centerController
                         leftDrawerViewController:leftController
                         rightDrawerViewController:nil];
self.drawerController.openDrawerGestureModeMask = MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll;
self.drawerController.closeDrawerGestureModeMask = MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll;
[self.drawerController setDrawerVisualStateBlock:[MMDrawerVisualState slideVisualStateBlock]];

self.drawerController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:self.drawerController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

well, my `leftController` is this one on the storyboard:
[image] [image]

and then **this is when it doesn't call `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` but `viewDidLoad` is called perfectly.**

if I empty it (so, when I don't have **any** view inside the main view) it works perfectly:

[image]

do you have any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the whole Storyboard and redoing it solved the problem.